# php check if a string contains special character and split the character

Tags: php

I have a string `classone insertclass_182 classtwo`.

I want to check if the string contains `insertclass_` And if the string contains `insertclass_`, I want to save the Numbers after the sign `_` in a variable. In this case: 182. But the number also can be another number ... for example `insertclass_4`

Thanks!

Comment: Check out `strpos` and `explode`, probably a good start. If you want any more help than that, please show us what you have tried so far.

Comment: `if (strstr(youstring, 'insertclass')) array_shift(explode(' ', array_pop(explode('insertclass_', yourstring))));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that with a regex :

```
<?php

$string = 'classone insertclass_182 classtwo';    
$regex = '/insertclass_([0-9]*)/';    
$result = preg_match($regex, $string, $matches);    
var_dump($matches);
```

It will return :

```
array(2) {
  [0] =>
  string(15) "insertclass_182"
  [1] =>
  string(3) "182"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this code will helpful

```
<?php
$string="insertclass_4";
$pos=strpos($string, 'insertclass_');

if($pos!==false){
    $var=substr($string, strlen('insertclass_'));
    echo $var;
}
```